# How to add caption text to a Plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to add a descriptive text below a graphics, usually a `Plot`. The `PlotLabel` is not suitable for this, because I think it is better suited for small phrases, such as the plot title. I need to write something closer to a paragraph.

I tried using `Show[plot, Graphcis@Text["a long description here"]]`, but that places the text over the plot.

Additionally, automatic word wrapping over long lines is desirable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `Grid` or a `Column`.  For example,

```
text = ...;

Grid[{{Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 π}, ImageSize -> Scaled[1]]},
  {Style[text, FontSize -> Scaled[0.005], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}},
  ItemSize -> Scaled[0.45]]
```

[image: 1]

Using `Scaled` for sizing (especially with fonts) works well for `Export`ing too.